# Get number from String with Jquery

Tags: jquery, string, numbers

In my system the var PRICE will have different formats depending on the CURRENCY configuration set by the user. So I can get values like:

**a)** price: $ 4.5 || **b)** price: 4.5 € || **c)** price: Bs. 4.5 || **d)** price: 4.5 ₵

I don't know whether the Currency symbol will be **before** or **after** the number and I don't know what symbol it is going to be (It's OpenERP framework so changing the format is not an option)

How do I get the number despite the currency symbol ??

Comment: Do you only want the number, or a value with a currency attribute?

Comment: Just look for numbers? `/[\d.]+/`? What do you care what symbols there are?

Comment: Maybe a "regex" is what I need, but I have no idea how to make it :(

Comment: I need the 4.5 as a number to use it in math operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get you string, your can replace every non digit character and the dot :

```
var number = '$ 4.5'.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '');
```

Then you can parse it :

```
number = parseFloat(number);
//Alternatively
number = +number;
```

Answer (score 1):

I aproached your problem by using JQuery to replace any character that isnt a number or a '.' (dot).

I created a few spans with values in like this:

```
<span>$4.10</span>
  <span>£7.76</span>
  <span>€23.44</span>
```

then created some JQuery to alert the values:

```
$("span").each(function(){
  var a = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
  alert(a);  
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle you can mess with: http://jsbin.com/xelameki/1/edit/

I hope it helps =)

Comment: It does work but the solution provided by Karl-André Gagnon is shorter . Thanxs for attending my question anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

I made the following test:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var price1 = "$ 4.5"; 
 var price2 = "4.5 €"; 
 var price3 = "Bs. 4.5"; 
 var price4 = "4.5 ₵";
 $("#test").append(price1.split(" ")[1]);
 $("#test").append(price2.split(" ")[0]);
 $("#test").append(price3.split(" ")[1]);
 $("#test").append(price4.split(" ")[0]);
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/H4QUu/1/

Comment: As I said: "I don't know whether the Currency symbol will be before or after the number". 

Solution provided by Karl-André Gagnon is exactly what I need. Thanxs for attending my question anyway :D